# Difficulty with setters

Tags: java

I having a class named Shape which has two subclasses Shape1 and Shape2. In the Shape class I have variables Xpos and Xpos and methods namely:

```
public int getXpos(){
    return Xpos;
}

public void setXpos(int x){
    this.x = x;
}

// Same thing for y
```

Now let's just say in the class Shape, `x = 10`. Now when I inherit it:

```
public class Shape1{
    Shape1(){
        xPos = 100;
        // ...
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Shape2{
    Shape2(){
        xPos = 200;
        // ...
    }
}
```

But when I do Shape1.getX() in another program, I get 10 as a result. Can someone tell me why I'm not getting 100? Is the problem with the 'this' keyword?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and not consistent with the example. Please fix your question.

Comment: This question is various forms of confused.

Comment: Can you post your actual code, you probably are referencing the wrong object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xPos cannot be static. If it is static the same number will appear twice. (the original shape)

Answer (score 3):

The `getXpos()` method should look like this:

```
public int getXpos() {    
    return x;
}
```